# Syncing client for FTP?

Tags: sync, ftp

I am looking for a way to sync files inside certain folders in my computers. Instead of using Dropbox, I have a dedicated FTP server that  will handle the storage of the files. My question is, what software will let me achieve something similar to what Dropbox does? (Sync files when it's changed, etc)

I have already tried FTPBox but it is currently unstable (keeps crashing and closing randomly on almost every computer I've tried it on). FTPBox would pretty much fit my needs if it just didn't crash often. Are there alternatives to it?

I need something stable because I will not always be around the computers to monitor it and I just want something that works.

Comment: So you need to Sync certain folder on FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

Download a software called [syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/)

1 - Create a `new profile`

2 - Choose `synchronize`, `backup` or `mirror`

3 - Select folder from left, `ftp` on the right

4 - Setup as needed.

Enjoy.